# unity c# sprite continously changing color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to create this script which changes the color of the sprite when I execute the method OnMouseDown().
The color change  should execute every 2 seconds. In this code provided below the colors only change once for some reason.

I have already tried coroutines. But they didn't work for some reason.

Please help thanks,

```
public bool startstop = false;
SpriteRenderer m_SpriteRenderer;

IEnumerator Changecolor() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    int random = Random.Range(1, 4);
    if (random == 1) {
        this.m_SpriteRenderer = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        this.m_SpriteRenderer.color = Color.blue;
    } else if (random == 2) {
        this.m_SpriteRenderer = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        this.m_SpriteRenderer.color = Color.red;
    } else if (random == 3) {
        this.m_SpriteRenderer = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        this.m_SpriteRenderer.color = Color.green;
    } else {
        this.m_SpriteRenderer = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        this.m_SpriteRenderer.color = Color.yellow;
    }

    this.StartCoroutine("Changecolor", 3f);
}

private void OnMouseDown() {
    if (this.startstop) {
        this.StartCoroutine("Changecolor", 3f);
        this.startstop = !this.startstop;
    } else {
        this.StopCoroutine("Changecolor");
        this.startstop = !this.startstop;
    }
}
```

No errors just doesn't work.

Comment: You haven't really described what exactly happens. How continuously do the colours change? And what colours do you see?

Comment: What if you put debug messages in to say starting coroutine, stopping coroutine... what do you see - your code looks like it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `Collider` on the object? A `Collider` is needed to have the `OnMouseDown` event fired.

The code principally works, but is far from quality.
    - Only call `GetComponent()` once, then cache the result. This call is very expensive.
    - Initially you have to click two times, as the Coroutine will be stopped at the first click.

Here is the code with some improvements:

```
        public bool m_isRunning = false;
        public SpriteRenderer m_spriteRenderer;

        private void Start() {

            m_spriteRenderer = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        }

        private IEnumerator Changecolor() {

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

            int random = Random.Range(1, 4);
            if (random == 1) {
                m_spriteRenderer.color = Color.blue;
            } else if (random == 2) {
                m_spriteRenderer.color = Color.red;
            } else if (random == 3) {
                m_spriteRenderer.color = Color.green;
            } else {
                m_spriteRenderer.color = Color.yellow;
            }

            this.StartCoroutine("Changecolor", 3f);
        }

        private void OnMouseDown() {
            m_isRunning = !m_isRunning;

            if (m_isRunning) {
                StartCoroutine("Changecolor", 3f);
            } else {
                StopCoroutine("Changecolor");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the second parameter you pass in (`3f`)

```c#
StartCoroutine ("Changecolor", 3f);
```

does nothing since your `Changecolor` does not take any arguments ...

---

I would actually suggest to not use Coroutine here at all but rather [`InvokeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) and [`CancelInvoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html)

```c#
void Changecolor()
{
    // Either in Awake or as lazy initialization
    if(!m_SpriteRenderer) m_SpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    int random = Random.Range(1, 4);
    switch(random)
    {
        case 1:
            m_spriteRenderer.color = Color.blue;
            break;

        case 2:
            m_spriteRenderer.color = Color.red;
            break;

        case 3:
            m_spriteRenderer.color = Color.green;
            break;

        default:
            m_spriteRenderer.color = Color.yellow;
            break;
    }
}

private void OnMouseDown() 
{
    startstop = !startstop;
    if (this.startstop) 
    {
        InvokeRepeating(nameof(Changecolor), 0f, 2f);
    } 
    else 
    {
        CancelInvoke(nameof(Changecolor));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided works just fine, and sins you say the color changes only once, I assume you have a collider on the object that has the script attached, the only thing you should change is the continues call to `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>` because it is pretty costly and should only be called in either `Start` or `Awake` another thing, which isn't major, and there is nothing wrong with it, but it kind of rubs me the wrong way, is the creation of a new coroutine at the end of the old, why not do something like this:

```
private Coroutine _colorChanger;

private SpriteRenderer _renderer;

void Start() //Can be Awake, whichever you choose
{
    _renderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    if (_renderer == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("No sprite found.");

        return;
    }
    //This is performed if OnMouseDown is implemented, if you implement the Update with Input.GetKeyDown, then this can be removed
    var collider = GetComponent<Collider>();

    if (collider == null)
    {
        collider = gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>(); //or BoxCollider2D if you are applying the script to the sprite itself.
    }
    collider.isTrigger = true;

}

private void OnMouseDown() //this can be swapped out for what Saif wrote, a Update method which checks if the button is down, should be GetKeyDown instead of GetKey, having it that way will eliminate the need for a collider/UI element
{
    if (_colorChanger == null)
    {
        _colorChanger = StartCoroutine(ChangeColor(2f));
    }
    else
    {
        StopCoroutine(_colorChanger);

        _colorChanger = null;
    }
}

IEnumerator ChangeColor(float timeoutSec)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeoutSec);

        int random = Random.Range(1, 5); //Change max from 4 to 5

        if (random == 1)
        {
            _renderer.color = Color.blue;
        }
        else if (random == 2)
        {
            _renderer.color = Color.red;
        }
        else if (random == 3)
        {
            _renderer.color = Color.green;
        }
        else
        {
            _renderer.color = Color.yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

Update: just noticed something that others missed, you should change the `Random.Range(1, 4)` to `Random.Range(1, 5)` or else the yellow color will never come into effect.

[image: A preview of the color change using the above script, turn on and turn off]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, no issues in it except that the `OnMouseDown()` function will not be called since you are not clicking on any box triggers or any UI elements. Hence try to use update function as given below:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            if (startstop == false)
            {
                StartCoroutine("Changecolor", 3f);
                this.startstop = !this.startstop;
            }
            else
            {
                StopCoroutine("Changecolor");
                this.startstop = !this.startstop;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: not necessarily if it is over a game object this script is attached to it works just fine

Comment: @BugFinder It is given on this link that it can only be called if the user has pressed the mouse button over GUI element or a collider https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Comment: Indeed, but that doesnt mean it cant work on a game object which has a collider.  Throw the orignal mousedown script on a default cube, and replace the start/stop coroutines with debug logs and see it work

Comment: @BugFinder ah yes it should. Looks like OP's gameObject that contains SpriteRenderer does not contain any colliders.